# Error en Laravel, al ejecutar php artisan migrate:install

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo instalado vagrant y virtualbox para realizar el entorno de desarrollo.
y al ejecutar vagrant up, inicializa el servidor virtual correctamente, pero cuando ejecuto php artisan migrate:install me aparece el siguiente error

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexi¾n ya que el equipo de    destino deneg¾ expresamente dicha conexi¾n.

he revisado todas la variables del archivo .env y entán correctamente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `DB_HOST` en .env?

Comment: DB_HOST=localhost

Comment: ¿Probaste con 127.0.0.1?

Comment: si, ya lo probé con la IP pero sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Estás usando homestead?

Comment: pregunto. que es lo que queres hacer con migrate:install? migrate:install existe?? para cargar las migraciones es php artisan migrate asi pelado

Comment: Tu problema no es al ejecutar el comando migrate:install, el problema es de conexión. ¿Tienes acceso al servidor de base de datos el cual quieres migrar? Generalmente estos problemas son por autenticación

Comment: si la verdad después de tanto intentar encontré la solución , y era que estaba ejecutando php artisan migrate:install en mi servidor local y claro como no tenia MYSQL habilitado me generaba ese error, y Cuando lo ejecute desde vagrant me funciono correctamente y para que me funcionara de modo local solo inicie MYSQL y funciono correctamente, Pero muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios y por querer ayudarme.